How many tyres does this car need to travel 27000 miles?
A puzzle from Oswald Jacoby’s Mathematics for Pleasure (1962):
The MacDonalds are planning a long car journey of 27,000 miles. If they use tires that last 12,000 miles each, how many tires will they need, and how can they make the best use of them?
P.S I already know the answer to this one but the answer that I know of, seems more like one that came from trial and error rather than from a systematic approach. So, I seek a more intuitive answer.

is the vehicle front or rear or 4 wheel drive?

I assume the tyres aren't unidirectional.

@Criggie , there are a total of 4 tires.

@Neil If the tires are unidirectional, the proposed solutions will require a certain number of tires to undergo a one-time remount to swap directions. If the front and rear axles use different sizes (sports cars), then you need the same number of additional tires. This is equivalent to solving the same problem but with 2, 2-wheeled motorcycles instead of one four-wheeled car.

The question seeks a "systematic" or "intuitive" answer, so I'll focus
on the reasoning I used to develop a solution schedule (which is
essentially the same as ilikecorgis').
As a first step, observe that

 the total tire-miles of required wear is 4*27k = 108k, so we need at
 least 108k/12k = 9 tires to have the required total wear.

Next, observe that

 if we can do 15k miles with 5 tires, then the other 12k are trivial,
 so we'll try to solve that (15k with 5) first.

Now, in my view, the key insight needed to develop a schedule is that

 you must never have fewer miles to travel than available wear on
 any single remaining tire.

For example,

 if at some point in a candidate schedule we have only 5k
 of travel to go but a remaining tire with 7k of wear, then that tire
 will necessarily have at least 2k of remaining wear when we arrive,
 which is bad because we know there is no margin of available wear.

From there, it turns out that

 a successful schedule simply falls out of maintaining the invariant
 that remaining travel distance is always greater than or equal to
 the largest remaining tire wear, and that this invariant can be
 maintained by swapping in the tire with the greatest remaining wear
 whenever at the threshold of violating it.

In particular:

 Initially we have 15k of travel remaining and 5 tires with 12k of
 wear.  So we go 3k miles on 4 of them, but must then swap since the
 5th tire still has 12k of wear and only 12k of travel remain.


 After swapping one tire, we have 12k of travel remaining, 4 tires
 with 9k of wear (3 on the car), and one with 12k.  So go another
 3k, at which point we must again swap because the unused tire has
 9k of wear and only 9k of travel remains.


 After swapping again, we have 9k of travel, 3 tires with 6k (2 on
 the car), and 2 with 9k.  After another 3k we have to swap due to
 the spare tire's remaining wear equaling the remaining travel, 6k.


 After swap #3, we have 6k of travel, 2 tires with 3k (one on the
 car), and 3 with 6k.  We can again go 3k before risking violating
 the invariant.


 After swap #4, we have 3k of travel, 4 tires with 3k (all on the
 car) and 1 tire with 0k.  Finish the trip, perfectly consuming all
 remaining wear.

In summary:

 In this particular case, a schedule emerges without any
 choices needed, just from that one insight.

Regarding the number of swaps:

 For the 15k portion, there are 4 tire swaps.  For the complete 27k trip, that makes 8 total swaps since we need 4 swaps between the 12k and 15k segments (regardless of which is done first).

This is an optimal number of swaps because

 every hub (a place a tire could go) must travel 27k.  If any hub is only swapped once, the maximum travel distance would be 24k.  Therefore every hub must be swapped at least twice, thus the minimum number of total swaps is 2*4 = 8.


This is essentially my "pandiagonal" solution with the last five tires, the first four being run separately beforehand.

Very good answer. So, your method requires a total of 8 swaps, right? You should also explain why 8 swaps is the minimum. That is, there's no other method that can use fewer than 8 swaps.

@HemantAgarwal Edited accordingly.

Maybe sounds silly to you. But why is this wrong? The tires of the car move at the same time. So after 12,000 miles all of them need to be replaced. The new 4 tires also need to be replaced after another 12,000 miles. The car has now traveled 24,000 miles. Now the newer 4 tires travel for 3,000 miles to reach the desired 27,000 miles. The number of all tires used is 12.

@EtackSxchange The main challenge of the puzzle is to devise a way to make the trip using the minimum number of tires.  You've described a way to do it with 12, but it can be done with fewer than that.

The minimum number of tires is easy to calculate:

 The total number of miles driven by all tires on the car is 27000*4, or 108000. Each tire can get them 12000 miles, so the minimum number is 108000/12000 = 9 tires.

What's more interesting is optimizing their use; I'm assuming that means minimizing the number of times they have to be changed.

 We can safely use the first set of 4 tires to drive the first 12,000 miles without replacements. Now, we have 5 tires remaining for 15,000 miles. Fortunately, these remaining 15,000 miles divides quite nicely into 5 parts of 3,000 miles each. If each tire of the remaining 5 drives for exactly 4 of those 5 parts, they will accumulate exactly 12,000 miles each. Let's see if this is possible:


 At 15,000 miles, we replace one tire with the unused tire, giving us one spare with 9,000 miles remaining. At 18,000 miles, we replace a different tire with the new spare; the spare will have 6,000 miles remaining. At 21,000 miles, we replace one of the remaining two that have not yet been replaced with the spare. Then, at 24,000 miles, the one remaining tire that has not been replaced will wear out, so we replace it with the final spare. Then, every tire will have 3,000 miles on it, which will barely get us to 27,000.

Counting up the number of replacements, we learn that the minimum number of replacements appears to be

 8.


Trivial proof of minimal number of replacements: 27000>2*12000 so each wheel must be replaced at least twice during the trip.

From other answers we know the number of tires. Here is offered a usage pattern that also requires minimal tire changes.

>

Each row is a tire and each column is 3000 miles; tires used in each 3000-mile leg are indicated by the filled squares. If the matrix is revealed we see that each tire is used in four legs and three tires "overlap" from one leg to the next.
If we imagine that this is a trip around the world, then the left and right edges are joined to make a cylinder. The usage retangles then merge into four parallel helix-diagonals, as broken diagonals are reconstituted by this wrapping procedure. These are called pandiagonals, and they play a major role in the theory of Latin squares and magic squares.

really great diagram!
